# drop down field list problem in Delphi 10.4

Tags: delphi

In Delphi 10.4 Version 27.0.37889.9797

I can pick an item correctly from the drop down list of options for completing code but only if it is sorted by Scope, and not if it is sorted by Name.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This question has way too less information to be answered. Please be more specific about what you have, what you do, what you expect and what you get. Best create a small sample program showing that.

Comment: @UweRaabe: The OP is talking about the IDE and its Code Insight autocompletion dropdown (Ctrl+Space).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, Thanks. If I read it with that background knowledge I can understand it a bit better.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What do you mean by "pick an item" specifically? I can start a new VCL Forms application, drop a TEdit on it, create an event handler for the form's OnCreate, and type `Edit1.`, and the list displays sorted by scope. I right-click that list, choose "Sort by name", and then type `Al`, and the list highlights `Align`, which I can choose just by hitting Enter. What are you doing differently?